# python pandas, stock data in panel structure

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, panel, vectorization

I have pulled dates and stock price data in from a csv file and am learning to use python/pandas for analysis. I started to create the basic data in a dict, which I then used to populate a panel. I have Wes McKinney's book and the 0.15.2 docs from 12/2014 - I do understand that panel functionality is slightly behind dataframe/series, but I decided to give it a go because I didn’t want the number of columns to get out of hand. However, I’ve hit a wall and can't seem to troubleshoot from existing SO content.

Each stock should represent a dataframe in the panel - and I am adding columns as I go.

```html
# data_raw = df with 4 columns = 'Date' and prices for 3 stocks
list_stocks = ['AAPL','MSFT','NEM']
per_ma = 5
price = 'PX'
ma = 'MvgAvg'

dict_main = {}
for stock in list_stocks:
    dict_main[stock] = {}
    dict_main[stock]['Date'] = data_raw['Date'] 
    dict_main[stock][price] = data_raw[stock]    
    dict_main[stock][ma] = pd.rolling_mean(dict_main[stock][price], per_ma)

pan = pd.Panel(dict_main)
```

Then I am trying to use basic formulas with rolling lookback windows to further build out the data in the panel. Here I am trying to populate +1 in pan[stock][overund] if price > ma OR -1 if price < ma... but only if it hasn't been that same value in the past per_ma periods.

```html
for stock in list_stocks:
    pan[stock][overund] = 0
    pan[stock].ix[pan[stock][price] > pan[stock][ma], pan[stock][overund]] = 1
    pan[stock].ix[pan[stock][price] < pan[stock][ma], pan[stock][overund]] = -1
    for i in pan[stock][overund].index:
        if pan[stock].ix[i, pan[stock][signal]] not in tuple(pan[stock].ix[i-per_ma:i-1, pan[stock][overund]]):
            pan[stock].ix[i,pan[stock][signal]] = pan[stock].ix[i,pan[stock][overund]]
        else:
            pan[stock].ix[i,pan[stock][signal]] = 0
```

Very strange - the first part of the above is populating the pan[stock][overund] with all 0s, and the first column is all +1/-1s. This is the wall. I don't even know yet if the "for i in pan[stock][overund].index" is causing problems.

Hopefully my coding indiscretions have not offended the programming gods too much. I am just a simple trader looking to be more self sufficient on the research side. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is overund isn't defined, I think what you mean

```
pan[stock]['overund'] = 0
```

And accomplishing your task is simpe

```
pan[stock]['overund'] = pan[stock][price] > pan[stock][ma]
```

Also, if you're only looking at equity prices, take a look here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/remote_data.html#remote-data-yahoo

And if you're looking for more help, I'd be happy to help: engineerededge@gmail.com

Comment: hi EngineeredE - sorry I have not come back sooner. Unfortunately, overund is defined (I should have made that clear) and the code isn't working for another reason. Do you have an opinion if a hierarchical index solution is a better way to go (than a panel) working in pandas?